# Sequence and function which share the same values past 1 but sequence converges and function diverges.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

This is a homework problem so I would prefer if nobody gave the answer away. My problem is:

A sequence $\{a_n\}$ and a function $f(x)$ for which $a_n=f(n)$ for every $n\ge1$, such that $\displaystyle \lim_{n\to\infty} a_n$ converges but $\displaystyle \lim_{x\to\infty} f(x)$ diverges: $a_n=$____________ , $f(x)=$____________

I'm thinking that there should be some different behaviour before one, but I'm a little confused on how their limits could be different if they have the same values as $n\to\infty$. I was thinking of something like having a series for $f(x)$ or an area function, but I'm not exactly sure how to put that into definite equations.

Comment: $f$ need not be continuous, so its values for $x\not\in\mathbb{N}$ could grow rapidly. You can also just define something piecewise. No need to specify explicit equations unless it asks you to.

Comment: Think of a function that is $0$ for all $n \in \mathbb N$ but does not have a limit at $+\infty$.

Comment: What a rare first sentence to a question. Also, are you sure you've copied the question down properly? The question seems a bit weird to me.

Comment: ‘An answer’, not ‘the answer’ - there are infinitely many answers.

Comment: Hint: Diverges means "does not converge".

Comment: I don't think the question has been copied down correctly, and I'm confused by the upvotes.

Comment: Keyword: Oscillations.

Comment: I got it, thanks everyone! I ended up using a piecewise function as I was on a deadline, but now I realize I could've just used a trigonometric function instead thanks to Jose27.